# Javascript: How to get Browser Zoom level using third party

Tags: javascript, flash, browser

How to get browser zoom level in all known browsers?
This is a new workaround for [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

The idea is to use flash or [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) to find the solution.

For now found one solution using flash.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a flash file with JavaScript bridge like this:

```
[SWF(width='100',height='100')]
public class SizeHack extends Sprite
{
    public function SizeHack()
    {
        if(stage){
            onAddToStage();
        }
        else{
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);
        }
    }

    protected function onAddToStage(event:Event = null):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);

        // security settings to allow scripting between domains
        Security.allowDomain("*");
        Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");

        // register to javascript
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("getSize", onSizeRequet);

        // stage scale mode must be noscale
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    }

    private function onSizeRequet():Number
    {
        if(!stage){
            return 0;
        }
        return stage.stageHeight;
    }
}
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("FlashResizer", "10.0.0");

    function getBrowserZoom()
    {
        return swfobject.getObjectById("FlashResizer")
            .getSize();
    }
</script>

<div id="flashResizerDiv" style="position: absolute; display: block; height: 100px; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100" id="FlashResizer">
        <param name="movie" value="resizer.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="resizer.swf" width="100%" height="100">
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>
```

Now when you call `getBrowserZoom()` you will get the exact zoom of the browser.

Comment: That gets the unscaled height not the browser zoom level. You need to do more math. Where is the rest of your code?